# what does this function nullParcelReleaseFunction do?

Tags: android, c++

In android code hardware/ril/libril/ril.cpp there is this function [nullParcelReleaseFunction](https://github.com/android/platform_hardware_ril/blob/master/libril/ril.cpp#L424):

```
void nullParcelReleaseFunction (const uint8_t* data, size_t dataSize,
                                    const size_t* objects, size_t objectsSize, 
                                        void* cookie) {
    // do nothing -- the data reference lives longer than the Parcel object 
}
```

It seems this function is not called anywhere and it exists in the first code commit, so what does this stub definition do exactly, is it some compiler trick to affect generated binary code?